# Alias type names of remote GraphQL schema

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, graphql-tools

I am using makeRemoteExecutableSchema in graphql-tools to retrieve a remote schema and I am then merging it with a local schema.  I would like to add a prefix to the type names on the remote schema.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to do a schema transform.

I assume you want to prefix the field names with something like someprefix_field_name, like you would prefix table names in a database? There is plenty of documentation for this, first in this example:

https://github.com/hasura/schema-stitching-examples/blob/master/schema-transform/index.js

and also look at the function `RenameRootFields()` in graphql-tools, as documented here:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-transforms#Modifying-root-fields